# JSON from MySQL and a PHP Class

Tags: php, mysql, json

I´m having this issue, I did the mysql query inside a class and then wanted to extract the sequence in a JSON format (up to this everything ok), then tried to decode the JSON to put inside different variables the fields needed, but it keeps showing me just the array secuence, example:

```
public function Users() {
    $array = array();
    //$connection to db;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$variable."'");
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $users = array(
        'id'=>$data['id'],
        'username'=>$data['username'],
        'name'=>$data['name'],
        'lastname'=>$data['lastname']
    );  
    $user = json_encode($users);
    echo $user;
}
```

Then in a another page I tried to deode the secuence like this:

```
include"class.php";
$user = new Query();
$usr = json_decode($user->User());
echo $usr->id;
```

but my result is:

```
{"id":"1","username":"someone","name":"Name","lastname":"Last"}
```

why, is the class causing the conflict?, how can I use a simpleclass to use it whenever I want to later on the run?

Thanks,

Comment: As a note, you should probably get into better naming practices.  You user $user, $users, Users() and $usr and they are all different things.

Comment: Was just trying to post it in a descriptive way. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion and appreciate your call

Comment: Thanks JMax, Good advice, how can this be possible? I´m new at stackoverflow

Comment: @JMR Why did you change the selected answer from mine to his, when they both have the same answer?

Comment: To be honest with you, I tried to give you both the correct answer (like I said I´m new at stackoverflow) if I did something wrong please let me know so it won´t happen anymore to anyone else. Apologize if I did something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echoing `$user` in your `Users()` function. You need to return it instead.

`return $user;`

Answer (score 2):

Don't `echo` $user, you need to `return` $user.  echo doesn't return a value, it outputs it to the buffer.

```
public function Users() {
    $array = array();
    //$connection to db;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$variable."'");
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $users = array('id'=>$data['id'], 'username'=>$data['username'], 'name'=>$data['name'], 'lastname'=>$data['lastname']); 
    $user = json_encode($users);
    return $user; // this is what I changed
}
```

User `Users()` instead of `User`:

```
include"class.php";
$user = new Query();
$usr = json_decode($user->Users()); //I also changed this because you only had "User"
echo $usr->id;
```

Comment: Nice!!! yup maybe that was the issue, the echo instead of the return, it´s working. Thankyou very much